# Videojs wrong frame rate

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, rtmp, video.js

I'm trying to play video with 5fps using VideoJS.

If I'm using HLS video-data format video plays correctly.

Yet If I'm using adobe flash player video is shown as 25fps.

Is it possible to change framerate for VideoJS RTMP streaming?